# GoogleSheet: Split the last two Capitalized characters in a String into two columns

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, split, multiple-columns

In examples, three cells contain these values:

```
ATRAAtara Biotherapeutics, Inc.
PYPLPayPal Holdings, Inc.
AABOSAcumen Pharmaceuticals, Inc.
```

QUESTION:

What is the GoogleSheet formula to 1) Target the first word (e.g. "ATRRAtara") to then 2) split into two columns specifically the last two Capitalized Characters (e.g. "ATR" & "RA" ) into two separate columns.

In example `"ATRAAtara"` would exist in 3 Columns

```
Column1: ATRA
Column2: Atara
Column3: Biotherapeutics, Inc.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA({
 REGEXEXTRACT(A1:A5, "([A-Z]+)[A-Z]"), 
 REGEXEXTRACT(A1:A5, "[A-Z]+([A-Z].+? )"), 
 REGEXEXTRACT(A1:A5, " (.+)")}))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(A2:A="",,{ IF(LEFT(REGEXEXTRACT(LEFT( TRIM(REGEXEXTRACT(REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A, "(\w+)"),".+[A-Z]")),LEN(TRIM(REGEXEXTRACT(REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A, "(\w+)"),".+[A-Z]")))-1), ".."),1)=RIGHT(REGEXEXTRACT(LEFT( TRIM(REGEXEXTRACT(REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A, "(\w+)"),".+[A-Z]")),LEN(TRIM(REGEXEXTRACT(REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A, "(\w+)"),".+[A-Z]")))-1), ".."),1)<>TRUE,LEFT( TRIM(REGEXEXTRACT(REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A, "(\w+)"),".+[A-Z]")),LEN(TRIM(REGEXEXTRACT(REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A, "(\w+)"),".+[A-Z]")))-1),RIGHT(LEFT( TRIM(REGEXEXTRACT(REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A, "(\w+)"),".+[A-Z]")),LEN(TRIM(REGEXEXTRACT(REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A, "(\w+)"),".+[A-Z]")))-1),LEN(LEFT( TRIM(REGEXEXTRACT(REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A, "(\w+)"),".+[A-Z]")),LEN(TRIM(REGEXEXTRACT(REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A, "(\w+)"),".+[A-Z]")))-1))-1)), CONCAT(REGEXREPLACE(TRIM(REGEXEXTRACT(REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A, "(\w+)"),".+[A-Z]")),LEFT( TRIM(REGEXEXTRACT(REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A, "(\w+)"),".+[A-Z]")),LEN(TRIM(REGEXEXTRACT(REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A, "(\w+)"),".+[A-Z]")))-1),""),REGEXREPLACE(REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A, "(\w+)"),TRIM(REGEXEXTRACT(REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A, "(\w+)"),".+[A-Z]")),"")), TRIM(REGEXREPLACE(A2:A,REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A, "(\w+)"),""))}))
```

[image]

Comment: The formula from Osm doesn't accomodate the scenario, whereby there's a secondary Capitalized Character blob at the end of 1st word.
    
For example: 

SOFISoFi Technologies, Inc.

The split is incorrect: "SOFISo" instead of Column1: "SOFI" & Column2: "SoFI"

Comment: @HelpMePlease its fixed now a minor typo take a look

Comment: Using 

'ccode'
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA({
 REGEXEXTRACT(A1:A5, "([A-Z]+)[A-Z]"), 
 REGEXEXTRACT(A1:A5, "[A-Z]+([A-Z].+? )"), 
 REGEXEXTRACT(A1:A5, " (.+)")})) '/ccode'

Comment: What do you mean there is something wrong with your comment

Comment: How do you add a rule that says, if the transposed colume value is (1) more or equal to 4 characters and (2) have repeating values in the first two characters, then delete the initial character. For example, COL1 generated values "EENVB", "KKSPN", "WWBEV" should be tranposed to "ENVB", "KSPN", "WBEV" instead.

Comment: @HelpMePlease in my answer `LEFT( TRIM(REGEXEXTRACT(REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A, "(\w+) "),".+[A-Z]")),LEN(TRIM(REGEXEXTRACT(REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A, "(\w+) "),".+[A-Z]")))-1)` simplified `LEFT( A2, LEN(A2)-1 )` to select the word minus `1` character.

Comment: Formula generates error: Function REGEXEXTRACT parameter 2 value "(\w+) " does not match text of Function REGEXEXTRACT parameter 1 value "KKSPN".

Comment: Full text of KKSPN?

Comment: I got it to work. @osm THANK YOU SO MUCH. How did you even keep track writing that code!

Comment: By dividing the problem and nesting, I'll do a an explanation later if its helpfule accept and vote up. glad it worked.